# Adding the IP Failover on FreeBSD

Tags: ip, freebsd, failover

I've just bought a dedicated server in `OVH.com` and they are sending me some warnings in email that I haven't configured my IP Failover address correctly and they're going to block this failover within 24 hours if I won't take any actions.

So, the question is, how should IP Failover be configured properly in FreeBSD 8.2?

Comment: What *kind* of failover (CARP between two machines? Multiple NICs failing over if the link goes down?)

Comment: I think this one: Multiple NICs failing over if the link goes down.

Comment: The answer to that question substantially changes the answer (multiple NICs in one box is `lagg(4)` -- Link aggregation (see James' answer).  Multiple machines passing around one address to make sure stuff stays up when one machine goes down is `carp(4)` - the `C`ommon `A`ddress `R`edundancy `P`rotocol.  For extra redundancy you can even combine the two :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `lagg(4)` ([FreeBSD Handbook entry](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/network-aggregation.html)). The `ifconfig` commands you need are:

```
ifconfig em0 up
ifconfig em1 up
ifconfig lagg0 laggproto failover laggport em0 laggport em1 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

(Substitute em0, em1, IP address and netmask as appropriate.)

The equivalent for `rc.conf` is:

```
ifconfig_em0="up"
ifconfig_em1="up"
cloned_interfaces="lagg0"
ifconfig_lagg0="laggproto failover laggport em0 laggport em1 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0"
```

Comment: +1 for linking to the handbook, source of all FreeBSD knowledge (and a pretty darn good general *NIX reference)